# group by dropdown list component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, ecmascript-6, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdown list component using the following package.

http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DropdownList/

and I want to show the list items in group, I am able to show the data without group but need to display in group by men and women. Below is my data format.

```
"data": [
  {
    "categoryName": "Men",
     "children": [
      {
       "categoryName": "Apparel",
       "categoryId": 2742
      },
      {
       "categoryName": "Fragrances",
       "categoryId": 2746
      }
     ]
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Women",
     "children": [
      {
       "categoryName": "Apparel",
       "categoryId": 2742
      },
      {
       "categoryName": "Fragrances",
       "categoryId": 2746
      }
     ]
  }
]
```

Below is my display component.

```
<DropdownList
 id={id}
 onChange={(e) => callbackFun(className, e)}
 data={data[0].children}
 value={value}
 inputProps={inputProps}
 valueField={keyVal}
 textField={keyName}
 placeholder={placeholder}
/>
```

Image of a dropdown needed.[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you need? From what I see, your data is already grouped by gender, which means if you were to render the list in order, you'd get your males first, followed by your females (`data[0].children` would get rendered first, and then `data[1].children`, depending on how you transform the returned data)

Comment: @MikeK `data[0].children` is just for example, I will have to only pass `data`, I want to render the data in dropdown in group by men and women. Edited my question and uploaded image of sample dropdown needed. I need a way to transform the data accordingly.

Comment: Adding `groupBy={data => data.categoryName}` and `itemComponent={({ item }) =>
          item.children.map(child => <div>{child.categoryName}</div>)
        }` Props was enough for me

Comment: @AlxRodav Thanks for the reply, this renders the data correctly in group by men and women, but it does not select individual item in the list, the whole group is getting selected when I click on the select options.`<DropdownList
onChange={(e) => callbackFun(className, e)}
groupBy={data => data.categoryName}
itemComponent={({ item }) => item.children.map(child => <div>{child.categoryName}</div>)}
data={data}
value={value}
valueField={keyVal}
textField={keyName}
/>`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Yes I have changed my implementation and I have selected the most appropriate answer. Although I was looking to implement something with this package. http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DropdownList/

Comment: It your expectations of that repo was to style your drop-downs, you may find tons of CSS frameworks out there that will provide consistent styling not only to drop-downs but to the rest of your UI, those are, to name a few: [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/), [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/), [Semantic UI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/), [React Antd](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what extra value does the repo you're referring to deliver. However, to render your options in groups, you may simply employ [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) elements on render:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const sampleData = {"data":[{"categoryName":"Men","children":[{"categoryName":"Apparel","categoryId":2742},{"categoryName":"Fragrances","categoryId":2746}]},{"categoryName":"Women","children":[{"categoryName":"Apparel","categoryId":2742},{"categoryName":"Fragrances","categoryId":2746}]}]}

const DropDown = ({data}) => (
  <select>
    <option selected disabled>Select...</option>
    {
      data.data.map(({categoryName, children}, key) => (
        <optgroup label={categoryName} key={key}>
          {
            children.map(({categoryId, categoryName}) => (
              <option key={categoryId}>
                {categoryName}
              </option>
            ))
          }
        </optgroup>
      ))
    }
  </select>
)

render (
  <DropDown data={sampleData} />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
const Category = ({ category }) => <optgroup label={category.categoryName}>
        {category.children.map(({ categoryName, categoryId }) => <option key={categoryId} value={categoryId}>{categoryName}</option>)}
</optgroup>

const DropDownList = ({ data }) => <select name="stores" id="stores">
    {data.map(element => <Category category={element} />)}
</select>

const App = () => <DropDownList data={data} /> // either App or whatever other component that will render DropDownList with the fetched data
```

Your parent `DropDownList` component will hold your categories, in this case your `men` and `women` types of stores (or whatever it may be), which will be housed in the `Category` component.

This should render something similar to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup).